# Glob module returning wrong value

Tags: python-2.7, glob

I have bunch of folders like below example and inside each folders have following number of files. Now when I want to know how many files are inside Pos2 folder then I am getting wrong output. For other folders it is giving correct. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
./a/Pos2/              8497 files              
./a/Pos22/             4227 files 
./a/Pos23/              2052 files 
./a/Pos26/              2633 files 

import glob
DIR='a/Pos2'
files = [f for f in glob.glob(DIR + "**/*.mat")]
len(files)
```

I am getting the answer 17409. It is adding the files from all folders. I don't why. 
Any clue what is happening?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> DIR='a/Pos2'
> files = [f for f in glob.glob(DIR + "**/*.mat")]
> ```

`DIR + "**/*.mat"` results in `"a/Pos2**/*.mat"`, which matches all of `./a/Pos2/*.mat`, `./a/Pos22/*.mat`, `./a/Pos23/*.mat`,  `./a/Pos26/*.mat`.

To only find the files in `a/Pos2`, use `"a/Pos2/*.mat"`, or `DIR + "/*.mat"`.

Or, to find all files in all subfolders of `a/Pos2`, use `"a/Pos2/**/*.mat"`, or `DIR + "/**/*.mat"`. Note the additional `/`.